# Can somebody help me understand what this ActiveMQ error message means?

Tags: activemq-classic

Every few minutes my ActiveMQ app fails with this error:

```
Unexpected error occurred: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.activemq.command.BrokerId cannot be cast to class org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerId (org.apache.activemq.command.BrokerId and org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerId are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Can somebody explain what this error means and how I might be able to handle this?

There's only one bit of the code where I attempt to cast the message to another type. Could this be the source of my problem?

```scala
def onMessageFunction(msg: Message): Unit = {
    val messageText: String = msg.asInstanceOf[ActiveMQTextMessage].getText
    val parsedXml: Elem     = scala.xml.XML.loadString(messageText)
    val topicName: String   = get_topic_name(parsedXml)
    val topic: String       = s"json_${topicName.toLowerCase()}"
    val jsonText: String    = XML2Json.xml2Json(XML2Json.fixMessages(parsedXml))
    producer.produceText(topic = topic, text = jsonText)
  }
```

This is the relevant section of the log:

```
481495 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils {35} - Shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3b77e88b[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 29] is shutdown: true and terminated: true took: 0.000 seconds. 
481496 WARN  Main$ {35} - Captured exception: javax.jms.JMSException: Unexpected error occurred: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.activemq.command.BrokerId cannot be cast to class org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerId (org.apache.activemq.command.BrokerId and org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerId are in unnamed module of loader 'app') 
481503 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport {35} - Stopping transport ssl://api.bmreports.com/163.164.233.156:61616 
481504 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory {35} - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@641d57b0[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] 
481505 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport {35} - Closed socket Socket[addr=api.bmreports.com/163.164.233.156,port=61616,localport=1055] 
481505 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils {35} - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@641d57b0[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
```

Comment: Without a stack-trace it's impossible to say where the problem lies exactly. Could you add some logging to your `onMessageFunction` and perhaps *test* to see if `Message` is actually an instance of `ActiveMQTextMessage` before trying to cast it? That's standard procedure to avoid occurrences of `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Also, what version of ActiveMQ are you using?